# tkinter - python mantener iniciada una sesión de un sistema de venta , es posible?

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

hola gente que tal es posible mantener iniciada la sesión o simular hacerlo ?? en el sistema que estoy haciendo tengo al abrir el programa la ventana login  cuando se valida el usuario y clave del empleado entra y se abre la ventana del menú principal, la cuestión es que necesito que se refleje ese usuario en el menú hasta cerrar el programa, esto es posible?? no lo vi por ningún sitio web

```
    def login_ventana(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ventana_login = Toplevel()
        ventana_login.resizable(0,0)
        ventana_login.config(bg="white")

        #Centrar Ventana en pantalla
        ox,oy=ventana_login.winfo_screenwidth()/2,ventana_login.winfo_screenheight()/2
        ventana_login.geometry("=300x350+%d+%d" % (ox-200,oy-200) )


        Label(ventana_login,text="Ingreso de Vendedor", bg="dark turquoise", width="18",height="2", font=("arial 20 bold")).grid(row=0,column=0)

        # Nombre Usuario
        Label(ventana_login, text="Nombre y Apellido *",bg="white", fg="black",font="arial 20 bold").grid(row=1, column=0,pady=10)

        self.nombre_usuario = Entry(ventana_login, justify="center", width=15, font=("arial 15"),bg="dark turquoise")
        self.nombre_usuario.focus()
        self.nombre_usuario.grid(row=2, column=0)

        # Contraseña
        Label(ventana_login, text="Contraseña *",bg="white", fg="black",font="arial 20 bold").grid(row=3, column=0,pady=10)

        self.contraseña_login = Entry(ventana_login, justify="center", width=15,show="*" ,font=("arial 15"),bg="dark turquoise")
        self.contraseña_login.grid(row=4, column=0)

        #Ingresar
        Button(ventana_login, text="Ingresar", height= "2", width="30", font=("arial 10 bold"), bg="orange",command = self.login).grid(row=5,column=0,pady=15)

        ventana_login.mainloop()
    #  ---------------- Base de datos (login) -----------------  
    def login(self,*args,**kwargs):
        
        if len(self.nombre_usuario.get()) != 0 and len(self.contraseña_login.get()) != 0 :
            
            # Connect to database
            db = sqlite3.connect(self.db_nombre)
            c = db.cursor()
            
            usuario = self.nombre_usuario.get()
            clave = self.contraseña_login.get()
            
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM Vendedores WHERE Nombre_y_Apellido = ? AND Contraseña = ?', (usuario, clave))
            
            if c.fetchall():
                messagebox.showinfo(title = "Login correcto", message = "Usuario y contraseña correctos")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror(title = "Login incorrecto", message = "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta")
            
            c.close()
            self.nombre_usuario.delete(0, END)
            self.nombre_usuario.focus()
            self.contraseña_login.delete(0, END)
            
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Cuidado', 'No ingreso ningun dato.')
```

Comment: algo que te impida guardar el valor de la sesión iniciada con una variable y verificarla en cada ventana o algo así?

Comment: mm no te entendí bien , basicamente necesito que  al iniciar sesión no se cierre la sesión hasta que se cierre el programa , porque asi se que vendedor estuvo vendiendo  tal cosa me entendes? nose si se entiende lo que quiero decir

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es demasiado abierta, habría que ver cómo manejas el inicio de sesión en primer lugar.. También, te refieres a una sesión en la app tkinter? O a una sesión en por ejemplo una base de datos SQL a la que la app se conecta? (porque veo que pusiste el tag SQL)...

Comment: buen punto , si ! esta todo rodando sobre sqlite , quizás existe algun comando sql que no conozco  para que la sesión quede abierta , es una app de escritorio hecha con tkinter , python y sqlite , el inicio de sesión lo hago con una funcion ahora la pongo acá en una imagen para que entiendas como lo hice

Comment: @DannyTalent ahi deje las imagenes arriba, para que entiendas mejor si tenes otro medio par acontactarte mejor avisame quizas me puedas dar una mano gracias !

Comment: Maxi, mejor pega el código como texto, es un poco difícil de trabajar con imágenes. Pero creo que debería bastar con guardar ese objeto `db` para más adelante, así puedes crear otro cursor con esa misma conexión, y cuando se cierre el programa (o la sesión), haces `db.close()`

Comment: como quedaria ? ahora pego el codigo

Comment: ahi deje el codigo , no te entendi bien , pero si puedes corregirlo en el codigo seria buenisimo !

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109449/discussion-between-dannytalent-and-maxi-pintos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me "inventé" el resto del código, porque no está todo en la pregunta, pero espero que puedas entender la idea. Principalmente, la solución que se me ocurrió es simplemente **guardar el usuario que inició la sesión como un atributo** de tu ventana de login.

```
class Ventana_Login:
    usuario = ""

    def login_ventana(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ...

    def login(self,*args,**kwargs): 
        if len(self.nombre_usuario.get()) != 0 and len(self.contraseña_login.get()) != 0 :
            db = sqlite3.connect(self.db_nombre)
            c = db.cursor()
            
            usuario = self.nombre_usuario.get()
            clave = self.contraseña_login.get()
            
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM Vendedores WHERE Nombre_y_Apellido = ? AND Contraseña = ?', (usuario, clave))
            
            if c.fetchall():
                messagebox.showinfo(title = "Login correcto", message = "Usuario y contraseña correctos")
                self.usuario = usuario  # <----- Guardo el usuario inicializado como atributo
            else:
                messagebox.showerror(title = "Login incorrecto", message = "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta")
            ...
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Cuidado', 'No ingreso ningun dato.') 
        return self.usuario
```

Luego si quieres tener otra ventana:

```
class Otra_Ventana:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def verificar_login(self, usuario=""):
        if usuario != "":
            pass  # Acá haces lo que quieras hacer dependiendo del usuario
```

Como el string es `""` por default (vacío), hay que verificar si se modificó (por eso el `if usuario != ""`). Si deseas, puedes guardarlo en la nueva ventana también como self.usuario = usuario...

Luego, al instanciar cada ventana, puedes simplemente mandar el atributo de una ventana a otra de esta forma:

```
main = Ventana_Login()  # creas la ventana de login
main.login()  # haces el login
siguiente = Otra_Ventana()  # creas la siguiente ventana
siguiente.verificar_login(main.usuario)  # Ejecutas la opción verificar_login mandándole el atributo _usuario_ de la ventana de login (objeto main)
```

Comment: Danny muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo, y disculpa las molestias voy a intentar llevarlo a cabo cualquier cosa te consulto en el chat ! gracias !!